# Header text in bound field using resource key

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to add Resource key to the header text of a grid view but after a long, i have not being able to manage this issue.

I have tried coding like:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName"  HeaderText="<%$ Resources:ViewTC_CourseCategory,HeaderCategoryName %>"
                 ItemStyle-Width="12">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

my resource file contain value like:

```
HeaderCategoryName.Text           Category Name
```

It showing the following Error: `The resource object with key 'HeaderCategoryName' was not found`

What is the correct way to implement this requirement.Kindly help.

Comment: can you tell what are the names of your Resource file & the page where the gridView is present ?

Comment: Name of resource file:ViewTC_CourseCategory.ascx.resx Page name:ViewTC_CourseCategory.aspx

Comment: I tried implementing this:  <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName"  HeaderText="<%$ Resources:ViewTC_CourseCategory,HeaderCategoryName %>"
                     ItemStyle-Width="12">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

Comment: Your resource file Name is having 'ascx' ? can you confirm ?  since the Resource file name must be:ViewTC_CourseCategory.aspx.resx as the page name is: 'ViewTC_CourseCategory.aspx'

Comment: Sorry sir page name is ascx..

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
  void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.HeaderRow)
    {
      // use the index of your cell
      e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Your Resource file string";
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that Resource file Name and page name are as per the Convention used by ASP.NET to search for a local Resource file:

1.) If page name is: Sample.ascx, Resource file name must be: sample.ascx.resx.

2.) Also make sure that the  App_LocalResource folder (Containing the sample.ascx.resx) is inside UserControls folder.